# HAML creates unnecessary spaces while using loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In Rails with HAML, I want to create a simple line of spaces: ====== on the page, with variable length. However, the following code:

```
- 10.times do
  \=
```

renders the following:

```
= = = = = = = = = =
```

I want to get rid of the spaces in the middle of these equals signs, but I don't really have any idea how. I know with ERB you can use

```
<%= 10.times do -%>=<% end %>
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, tested, should work:

```
= "=" * 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
- 10.times do
  &= "="
```

Comment: Doesn't help, unfortunately. Produces a syntax error, unexpected tAMPER

Comment: Now it prints:
&#61; &#61; &#61; &#61; &#61; &#61; &#61; &#61; &#61; &#61;